# What is Owin? What is it's relationship to Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, owin

Can anyone give me a brief description of owin?

What is its relationship between asp.net mvc external log in?

and relation to Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google?

Comment: This is a question for google:  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/introduction-of-owin-and-katana-in-visual-studio-2013-previe/

Comment: Deeply appreciate to u. thanks !

Comment: Recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  `Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!`

Comment: I'll improve these ability after asking, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about OWIN at http://owin.org. That should give you some understanding about the structure and interface of the framework and how it is used to separate any midware, e.g. MVC from a concrete server process e.g. IIS. Microsoft wants to adopt this framework/interface to make middleware like MVC available on more systems. Currently (MVC5) MVC is not yet a OWIN middleware, but parts like authentication already are. So this is why you have some assembly like `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` referenced in your project.

Comment: @Mithrandir what do you mean by "Currently (MVC5) MVC is not yet a OWIN middleware, but parts like authentication already are". is mvc is middleware then does an app is top layer and server is bottom layer according to terminology you used?